# Set a checkbox in Javascript dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Can someone please tell me how to set a checkbox dynamically in Javascript?

```
function displayResults(html){
    var v = html.split(",");
    document.getElementById('fsystemName').value = v[0];
    if (v[1] == "true"){
        document.getElementById('fUpdateActiveFlag').checked = true;
    }
}
```

So I am passing some values from my controller separated by commas. For the checkbox, when the value is true I want it to tick the box.

EDIT:
When a value is changed from a dropdown box it calls this displayResults method as its return statement:

```
$('#uINewsSystemList').change(function() {
    $.get("/live-application/SystemById", {systemid: $("#systemList").val()}, displayResults, "html");
```

I want it to update some other values such as textboxes and checkboxes. I can get the `fsystemName` to populate with the appropriate value but the `fUpdateActiveFlag` always stays unchecked.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't set its `checked` state in the JSP? That seems like a better option than trying to do it client-side.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Post more code and be clear with the problem.

Comment: Complete JSP would give total picture and opportunity to guide properly.

Comment: It's not even clear that you're actually calling `displayResults()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you posted a javascript example, not JSP.

In JSP you can use a for loop to write the checkbox like this:

```
<% for (Element element : elementList) { %>
<input type="checkbox" name="<%=element.getName() %>" value="<%=element.getValue() %>" <%=element.getChecked() ? "checked" : "" %> />
<% } %>
```

Will result in:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Cheese"> Cheese<br>
```

Comment: Apologies, I meant Javascript

Comment: If you are using jQuery, take a look to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript

Otherwise, document.getElementById('fUpdateActiveFlag').checked = true; should do the work